# SignalR Join Group From Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

When the user logs in on my site, they select from a dropdown which group they belong to.  On the login postback, as they are logged in, I'd like to assign them to the correct SignalR group.

As per the documentation [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#groupsfromhub), I can join it client-side via:

```
contosoChatHubProxy.server.joinGroup(groupName);
```

Is there a way to assign the group from the controller?  I can call the Hub like:

```
var hub = new NotificationHub()
hub.JoinGroup(selectedGroup);
```

but the Context in the hub method is null.  Is this possible, or am I approaching this problem incorrectly?  Thankyou for any advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't new up a hub like that; you can get the hub context and add a user to a group from external code like this:

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
hubContext.Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName);
```

Comment: That makes sense, but how do you go about getting the `ConnectionID` server side?

Comment: You have to pass it to the controller from the client. In javascript that's $.connection.hub.id

Comment: @dfowler so it is not possible to get the ConnectionId from the server?

Comment: @GoldnArms the automatic association between connection id and request only exists when it goes through a SignalR connection (then you can get it via Caller.ConnectionId); so if you make a regular HTTP request to a Web API endpoint, for example, there's no way to know which SignalR client the caller is unless you explicitly pass that information in

Comment: @LarsHöppner I understand, thnx for a great explanation